# Update database after creating entitys

Tags: spring, spring-data, jhipster, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I'm having a problem. Every time I update the JDL file by adding some entity or relationship, the database is not updated. And I think this is what causes that when I go to make a GET request, I get an "Internal Server Error". What I want is that every time I import the JDL file and run the gradlew command, the database is updated. How can I do it?

Comment: Each time you import the JDL, you must restart the java backend because that's when liquibase is run and Hibernate introspects database. Maybe it could be possible to do something with spring boot devtools, try to do some research and propose a pull request if you made it.

Comment: I understand. I will search information about Spring Boot DevTools, thank you for your help!